# How does one book a currency exchange loss?

Tags: united-states, corporate-earnings, foreign-currency, income-tax

How does one book a currency exchange loss?

**Let's assume:**

- I have an account in GBP.
- I have an account in USD.
- I pay taxes in USA.

**Let's assume following transactions:**

- I made 100k GBP in the beginning of 2016 and booked it at 150k USD.
- I converted 100k GBP to USD at the end of 2016 and received 125k USD.

**Tax time is there so let's assume:**

- I pay 25% taxes on income. That's 25% of 150k USD.

**Question:**

- How do I book the loss of 25k USD because of currency conversion?
- What if I only converted 50k GBP at the end of 2016?

Comment: Currency speculation losses?

Comment: @DJohnM This is not about speculation, but about being paid in another currency and how to book these deposits.

Comment: The IRS *may* say you received 150 K USD, and need to declare this;  bought GBP and held for a year, converted back to USD with a 25k USD loss in currency speculation...